# Detecting connection requests without looping

Tags: c++, sockets, loops, callback, sdl

I need to implement some kind of server which first waits for users to connect. I use C++ and SDL_Net, and my code currently checks socket activity in a loop. The problem is that is consumes a lot of CPU performance doing nothing actually, so I'm wondering if there's a way to detect connection request/socket activity with an event or some kind of callback registration? I'm not afraid of WinAPI so any solution is welcome.
Thank you in advance,

Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`SDLNet_SocketSet`](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/SDL_net/SDL_net_41.html#SEC41), create one, then check with [`SDLNet_CheckSockets`](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/SDL_net/SDL_net_46.html#SEC46) and [`SDLNet_SocketReady`](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/SDL_net/SDL_net_47.html#SEC47)

Comment: Thanks, it's working, don't know why I haven't tried this yet!

Answer (score 1):

What socket API are you using? Winsock? If so, you need to call [`listen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms739168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the socket to wait for incoming connections. This call will block the calling thread, so no CPU time is used while waiting.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx for more details.